# Combine background image properites into single CSS rule but not specificy background color?

Tags: css

I want an element with a class to always have the same background color. Depending on weather it has an additional class its background image will change.

This works fine however having to have separate rules for the different background properties is a little messy:

```
.class { 
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url("image1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}

.class.additional { 
  background-image:  url("image2.jpg"); 
}
```

This works but ive had to repeat 'grey' which isnt ideal for maintaining the code long term:

```
.class {
  background: grey url("image1.jpg") no-repeat right center;
}

.class.additional {
  background: grey url("image2.jpg") no-repeat right center;
}
```

Is there a way I have write all the background properties on one line, but not repeat the background color for both styles?

Comment: What if you write background: transparent url("image1.jpg") no-repeat right center; and after that you override the transparent with .grey {background-color: grey;}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the shorthand in the first rule and override just `background-image` in the second:

```
.class { 
  background: grey url("image1.jpg") no-repeat right center;
}

.class.additional { 
  background-image: url("image2.jpg"); 
}
```